# How to tag the container image in ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have image like this `3144113911111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod-my:1.2` it is already uploaded on `ECR`.

Now I want to tag this `latest` not only `1.2`

For example in local I can tag like this

```
docker tag 3144113911111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod-my:1.2 3144113911111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod-my:latest
```

However I want do this directly on the `ECR`

Is it possible?

My ideas are below.

1. run the docker command on ECR directly.
2. I can do the same thing by `aws ecr` command ?

Comment: I Google your question and the first answer is the solution to your problem

Comment: wooooooo , I found the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by connecting to ECR via shell, and then tagging and pushing the image using Docker.

Here's an example based on yours:

```bash
$ aws --profile YOUR_CLI_PROFILE ecr get-login-password \
  --region ap-northeast-1 | docker login --username AWS \
  --password-stdin 3144113911111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
$ docker tag prod-my:1.2 3144113911111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod-my:1.2
$ docker push 3144113911111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod-my:1.2
```

And you can find more details [here on the official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I am afraid it is a bit different what I want to do.  I want to tag the image already on `ECR`.